# inserting list in database using python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, list

i have two column sess_id and info in database, and i want to place list data only in info column 
 here is my code :

```
    import sqlite3

    database_list=['easy','mid']

    conn_two= sqlite3.connect('videojs.db')
    c=conn_two.cursor() 
    c.execute("INSERT INTO data VALUES (database_list)")
    conn_two.commit()
    c.close()
    conn_two.close()
```

and this is the erroe from it...

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\xampp\htdocs\eclipse_workspace\Project\check.py", line 7, in 
   <module>
   c.execute("INSERT INTO data VALUES (database_list)")
   sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: data
```

please correct me else suggest some other way...
and one more thing i only want o place data in one column other column "sess_id" is auto increment

Comment: It's telling you you don't have a table called "data". What's unclear about that? Of course, once you've fixed that, you will have another problem because you've passed the literal string "database_list" to the query, not the contents of that list.

Comment: the thing is that i do have a data table ...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass the literal string name of the variable. Instead, you have to specify the variable position with a `?`:

```
import sqlite3
database_list=['easy','mid']
conn_two= sqlite3.connect('videojs.db')
c=conn_two.cursor() 
c.execute("INSERT INTO data VALUES (?, ?)", database_list)
conn_two.commit()
c.close()
conn_two.close()
```

Comment: my database is in the xampp , i my localhost , is there some issue that we cant use sqlite for localhost like xampp or wampp...????